# How to use javascript method trigger to call vuejs method in laravel blade

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-blade

I am using google oauth2 authorization in a pop-up window.
I am trying to learn VueJS so the following code might have issues (if you spot them please be kind and point them)

**How can I hide the `Sign in with Google` button using vue when the authorization is completed?**

`login.blade.php`

```
<redirect-to-provider route="{{route('auth.scopes.redirect')}}" provider="google"></redirect-to-provider>
```

`RedirectToProvider.vue`

```
<template>
    <button v-on:click="popUpRedirect" class="btn btn-primary">
        Sign in with Google
    </button>

</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            route: {
                required: true,
            },
            provider: {
                required: true,
                default: "google"
            },
            scopes: {
                default: '',
            },
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },
        methods: {
            popUpRedirect: function () {
                return window.open(
                    this.route+"?provider="+this.provider+'&scopes[]='+this.scopes, '_blank',
                    'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0'
                );
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

`callback.blade.php`

```
                <script>
                    window.onunload = function() {
                        var win = window.opener;
                        if (!win.closed) {
                            win.console.log('signed in successfully');
                        }
                    };
                    window.close();
                </script>
```

So a the vue component renders a button. I click it and a pop-up window opens and redirects to google. I do the authorization flow and returns me to callback.blade.php. If user granted permissions I send to `login.blade.php` a console message with `signed in successfully` and then I do a `window.close();`

**I could hide the button using a javascript method instead of `console.log('signed in successfully');` but I cannot figure out how to use VueJS instead.**

Comment: you can access window object inside vue. then you can do your related logic